# Prove the following integral inequality: $\int_{0}^{1}f(g(x))dx\le\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{1}g(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, integral-inequality

Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous function from $[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$, and $f$ is monotone increasing, then how to prove the following inequality:
$$\int_{0}^{1}f(g(x))dx\le\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{1}g(x)dx$$

Comment: I'll be the first to say it - users are encouraged to say what they've done on a question so far/what might be a point of confusion so that people can deliver more helpful (and not redundant) advice.

Comment: yes, because it's hard and I have no idea to go any further. I just get a hint: how to estimate $f(x)$, then change $x$ to $g(x)$

Comment: Did you consider using the fact that $f$ as a continuous monotone function is differentiable almost everywhere?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

By the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals, there is a point $\xi \in [0,1]$ such that
$$
\int_{0}^{1}[f(g(x))-g(x)]dx=f(g(\xi))-g(\xi).\tag{1}
$$
Let $u = g(\xi)$.  Then
$$
f(g(\xi))-g(\xi) = f(u)-u \leq f(u) - uf(u) = (1-u)f(u),\tag{2}
$$
(the inequality is due to the fact that $0\leq f(u)\leq 1$).
Since $f$ is monotone increasing, $f(x)\geq f(u)$ for all $x$ in $[u,1]$. So
$$
(1-u)f(u) = \int_u^1 f(u)\,dx \leq \int_u^1 f(x)\,dx \leq \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx.\tag{3}
$$
Hence, by $(1),(2),(3)$, we have
$$\int_{0}^{1}[f(g(x))-g(x)]dx\leq\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx.$$
Rearranging,
$$
\int_0^1 f(g(x)) \,dx \leq \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx + \int_0^1 g(x)\,dx.
$$
Over!

Comment: I don't see at all how the penultimate line rearranges to the last line. Could someone possibly enlighten me?

Comment: @Jam Answered my own question. Substitute back $\int_0^1[f(g(x))-g(x)]\leq(1-u)f(u)$ to the left of the penultimate line. That didn't feel obvious.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, @Rienmann provided one. But it is an interesting corollary of this result:

$$\int_0^1 f(f(x)) dx \leq 2\int_0^1 f(x)dx$$

Also,

$$\int_0^1 f(x) dx + \int_0^1 f^{-1}(x) dx \geq 1$$

and

$$\int_0^1 f(x^2) dx \leq \frac{1}{3}+\int_0^1 f(x) dx.$$
An interesting question is when (for which functions) the last inequality becomes an equality.

Comment: Nice corollaries @ Vincent Granville

Comment: wow, interesting question, I just tried the techniques from variation of calculus for your last ineq., after a smooth perturbation, the original function just disappeared... I think this must not a question of variations of calculus. So I can just get the answer from the prove of Riemann, and the monotone continuous $f$ is not exist.

Comment: As someone mentioned somewhere else (social media), the second inequality is only defined for f(0)=0, f(1)=1, and then it's an equality (but the OP's inequality only proves 1/2 in the RHS, not 1)?

Answer (score 0):

For equality, we get:

$$\int_{0}^{u} f(x)dx = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = 0, \forall x \in (0, u)$$
$$\int_{u}^{1} f(u)dx = \int_{u}^{1} f(x)dx \Rightarrow f(x) = f(u), \forall x \in [u, 1)$$

for $f$ to be continuous, we need $u \in \{0, 1\}$, in other words, $f$ is constant. We quickly get that $g$ is constant zero.

As for Vincent's question, there is no equality in the last inequality because $x^2$ isn't constant. Proving a better bound would be more interesting. As pointed out by Clement, the second inequality is wrong and the corollary as a whole seems quite weak.