# An integral inequality about $f(f(x))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and monotonically increasing. Assume $f(0)=0$,$f(1)=1$. Prove:$$\int_0^1{f\left( f\left( x \right) \right) dx}\le 2\int_0^1{f\left( x \right)}dx
 $$Furthermore,please calculate:$$\underset{f\left( x \right)}{inf}\frac{\int_0^1{f\left( f\left( x \right) \right) dx}}{\int_0^1{f\left( x \right) dx}}
 $$

- My thoughts: based on what we know about the function $ f$, it is not difficult to conclude that $f(f(x))$ is the same as $f :f(f(0))=0,f((1))=1$,and $f\circ f$ is monotonically increasing and continuous.

  - In addition, the greater the deviation between function $f$ and line $ y=x $ at one point , the greater the deviation between $f\circ f$ and $f$ at that point.Therefore,I guess $inf=\frac{1}{2}$ when $f(x)=x^n(n \to \infty)$.
    However,I don't know how to porve the inequalit and the value of inf by rigorous proof.So I want to ask a master to teach me.Thank you!

*Finally,what would happen when we replace $f\circ f$ with $\underset{n}{\underbrace{f\circ f\circ \cdots \circ f}}$*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, see my comment, or see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276722/prove-the-following-integral-inequality-int-01fgxdx-le-int-01f).

For the second part, if we let $f(x) = x^n$ for $n$ positive or negative, then $f(f(x)) = (x^n)^n=x^{n^2}$ whose integral is $\frac 1{n^2 + 1}$, while the integral of $f(x)$ is $\frac 1{n+1}$, so the given ratio is $\frac{n+1}{n^2 + 1}$, which converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. However, the ratio is always positive, therefore the infimum must be zero.

Comment: Yes,you are right.Thank u very much! I am ashamed that I thought $(x^n)^n=x^{2n}$……

Comment: You are welcome! I  do like the question you gave, though : I will be recommending it to a professor I know currently taking a real analysis course.

Comment: Haha！I also want to know that whether “2” is optimum in this inequality？

Comment: Worth thinking about. The first way to think is to see the proof in the link and see if equailties can hold anywhere.